# Google Play beta version not installable

Tags: android, google-play, beta, android-tv

We want to start closed beta testing for an app which has a production version already published in the Play Store. The production app is for Android TV only, so it has these features set in the manifest:

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.software.leanback"
    android:required="true" />
```

Now the beta app should be for phones only, so the manifest misses the above lines (touchscreen implicitly defaults to true and leanback defaults to false), as we want to have seperate apks for TV and phones.
The problem now is, that although my Google account is authorized for the beta, the app does not show up in Google Play on my Nexus 5. If I follow the Play Store link from the testing page (`https://play.google.com/apps/testing/my.package.name`), I see a warning that my device is not compatible.

Does anyone have an explanation for this? Is it not allowed to have a beta version for a device configuration that is not already published in production? Or is this a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sometimes you need to wait 3 - 24 hours or more after uploading your app on playstore

Comment: Ok, the app is available now, after waiting for three days. You would actually expect Google to show some information of the status of the distribution and not just generic error messages or apps not showing up at all.